Stagnating water under elevated paver deck in terrace
(Sorry if the technical terms are incorrect; don't hesitate to fix them.)
In the recent apartment building I am living on, the terrace is made of concrete with no slope, with elevated pavers and water running underneath them.

The lack of slope and the position of the drain pipe allow some centimeters of stagnating water to remain under the pavers, breeding mosquitoes and some nasty larvae.


I'd like to minimize the amount of stagnating water to avoid mosquitoes during summer. Some possible solutions I've considered are:

Adding sand/gravel to the entire terrace, to prevent mosquitoes from being able to lay eggs;


Pros: seems like a sensible solution, from what I've found;
Cons: would require a lot of material, and also lifting almost every paver in the terrace; there are just a few millimeters between pavers, so I cannot just pour the sand/gravel between them. Also, I'm afraid that when it rains, the water volume flowing under the pavers will move the sand and make it clog the drain.


Adding some chemical products to prevent insects from laying eggs, such as silicone-based films on the surface of the water.


Cons: the water is not always stagnating, so the product would likely flow off when it rains.


Using some sponge or tissue with capillary action to lower the water level.


Pros: easy to install and test (at least in the corner);
Cons: I couldn't find the right material and/or dimensions.

Concerning number 3, I did try putting some sponge-like fabrics and foams. The idea is that, by bridging the foam between the lower part of the deck, and the end of the drain pipe (going slightly over it), the water would be drained by the fabric and slowly drop at the other end.
I found a material that works very well, but it's for household cleaning, and I cannot find it in large sizes:

Besides, it's a biodegradable material that simply disintegrated after 2 weeks outside.
Other than that, I tried some mattress foams, but while they "absorb" the water well, it does not "flow" to the other side, so in the end it does not work.
Would drainage felt help? Some kind of geotextile?
This seems to be a standard way of building such terraces, I don't understand how people are supposed to deal with insects in such cases.

Your location might matter.  For apartment building, your choices are usually limited to what you can do yourself.  Some type of insecticide might be all you can add yourself, anything that might change the draining/add weight should not be done yourself, leave it to building maintenance/owners.  Your local health department might help suggest/not fine building owners to do something to drain all the water.

This is in France. The local town has no specific ordinances against stagnating water. This is why I believe something like a draining mat or wick would be the best approach, since it's easy to undo. But I cannot find details about whether such fabrics work in this case (e.g. irrigation mats keep plants moist, but would they allow the water to percolate to the other side of the drain pipe? The only relevant website I found is this one (in French), but since it sells insecticides, I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Your problem appears to be that the invert of your drainage pipe is higher than the sump elevation of your "pit."  We can't see the rest of the bottom of your pit, but assuming the photo shows the lowest point, you want to fill up the bottom of the pit by the same amount across, up to the pipe invert.  What kind of material you use should be a nonporous material—anything porous will still allow mossies to breed.  Some kind of resin, perhaps...I dunno what's available in France.
If that's not the lowest point in the pit, you need to add more resin to the rest so it is the lowest point.
